# Search other apps content

Tags: android, search, android-contentprovider

I need to make an app, similar to Google Now, which would search other apps content that is exposed via Content Providers.

The problem I have, is that all resources I found talk about making your app searchable, but I need the opposite - how to search through all those apps? Is this a private API that only Google Now uses or can I also make such an app?

Currently, I managed to get a list of all searchable apps by reading all meta tags and filtering those with "android.app.searchable" but there must be a better way.

The logical flow should be:

- find apps with "android.app.searchable" meta tag
- read searchable.xml config to get the content provider
- query the content provider from search box